# Unable to stop Concurrent Session in Spring Boot (Keycloak Authentication Server)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak

I am able to implement authentication  functionality using  Spring Security and Keycloak(Working as expected). However, when I tried to stop concurrent login in the Spring Security configuration it is not working. I tried with keycloak configuration also ,however I came to know there is no such in build functionality/configuration to stop concurrent login.

**Spring Boot Keycloak Configuration is as follows:**

```
SessionRegistry sesionregistry=new SessionRegistryImpl();

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());

    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);

}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sesionregistry);
}

@Bean
public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    super.configure(http);

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/app/*").hasRole("user")
            //.antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin*").hasRole("admin")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)

            ; //for maximum 1 session for any user

}
```

Using this configuration, I am able to login however concurrent login are not disabled.

I tried to print Principal Object for same user different login and found that:
**Session 1:**

```
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@ec24d1c4:Principal: c8827230-1916-4026-923c-642be90d0d38; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@7f2460bd; Granted Authorities: ROLE_user, ROLE_uma_authorization
```

**Session 2:**

```
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@87138d52: Principal: c8827230-1916-4026-923c-642be90d0d38; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@1e21cde6; Granted Authorities: ROLE_user, ROLE_uma_authorization
```

Even the hash value to 2 principal object differes:

```
Session 1: Printing Principal HAsh Value: -1854104148
Session 2:     Printing Principal HAsh Value: -1904262684
```

I don't know how to solve the concurrent login issue. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Keycloak Version: Server Version 3.4.3.Final
Spring Boot Version: 1.5.10.RELEASE

Comment: Have you tried to have someone other than yourself try to start the same user session (same login) from a different machine?

Comment: Yes..on different machine also it is not working.

Comment: Try moving your sessionManagement and maxSessionsPreventsLogin lines ABOVE the top authorizeRequest() line and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Adam  sure I will give it a try

Comment: @Adam I tried that but it is not working